# how to keep default styles after media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have built a website [siavoush-re.co.uk](http://siavoush-re.co.uk) and have used media queries to adjust it to small screens.
I first made a default style so the website fits my 1280px screen and then used min width media queries from 240px to my regular size. So it looks something like this

```
default css 

@media (min-width: 240px) { //style }

@media (min-width: 320px) { //style }

......

@media (min-width: 1280px) { //style }
```

What I wanted to know is if there is way to undo all the changes done in the previous breakpoints and have it revert to the default style once the width reaches 1280px?

Comment: Can't you do: `@media (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 319px) { /* style */ } ` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want `max-width`-- 'change to this css up until this size'.

You can also combine these queries depending on your needs, for example:

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Yea that seems to do the trick, however it seems I would have to use it for all the breakpoints, it seems inefficient to have separate styles for all of them, is there a way to stop it once it reaches 1200px and then just revert back to original?

Comment: Well if you're using `min-width` you're saying 'after it's this big always do this'. If you don't want that, you'll have to use `max-width` instead or in combination as shown in the sample code.